# json_decode to array does not work

Tags: php, json

I am generating some json by the getCreditDetail function which I would like to convert to an array. The following does not work:

```
$obj = json_decode($kredit->getCreditDetail($_GET['id']));
print $obj['projekt'];
```

I would expect now, to get a "test" as result.

The  var_dump($obj); returns:

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
 object(stdClass)#3 (18) {
   ["id"]=>
   string(2) "37"
   ["0"]=>
   string(2) "37"
   ["projekt"]=>
   string(19) "test"
   ["1"]=>
   string(19) "test"
   ["cat"]=>
   string(3) "M&A"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, `json_decode` is returning as an object. To get it to return as an array, add the second parameter as true.

Change;

```
$obj = json_decode($kredit->getCreditDetail($_GET['id']));
```

To;

```
$obj = json_decode($kredit->getCreditDetail($_GET['id']), true);
```

#### I've noticed you're using a multidimensional array, read on;

So, I created a multidimensional array and encoded it by doing;

```
$array = array(0 => array(1 => "Unicorn", 2 => "Horse", 3 => "Rhino"));
$json= json_encode($array[0], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This returns JSON, like;

```
{"1":"Unicorn","2":"Horse","3":"Rhino"}
```

I accessed the JSON by doing;

```
$json = json_decode($json);
echo $json->{1};
```

Which returned "Unicorn"

Comment: I added the ,true and still have the same behavior. Accessing like $obj->betrag didn't help either

Comment: Okay, **Is it valid JSON**

Comment: It is, the var dump now looks like: array(1) { [0]=> array(18) { ["id"]=> string(2) "37" [0]=> string(2) "37" ["projekt"]=> string(19) (...) But I can't access it like $obj->projekt ...

Comment: The function that creates it is 
    return json_encode($sth->fetchAll());.

Comment: Okay. Utilise my edit regarding multidimensional array json_encode, with supplying `[0]`

Comment: I solved the problem by using fetch instead of fetchAll

Comment: Actually your hint with the multidimensional array made my day. this is it   echo $obj[0]['betrag'];

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear.